# Best way to make drawable images efficient?

Tags: android, xml, performance, imageview

I'm still learning how to build Android apps, and an issue I'm running into a lot in my design is how to display multiple images at once, without crashing and/or lag. I've seen multiple people suggesting you use LazyLoaders, or swap out how I do it, but I'm wondering what the best way for my specific design is, as it's relatively complex.

The design is roughly as follows: A header, with text and a profile picture. Then, a horizontal scrolling section with 3 cards inside. Each card contains a grid view of 9 photos (Therefore, the 3 cards contain 27 images.) Beyond that, there are a few more images below.

I've updated my drawables to be as low-res as possible without making the app look rubbish, but I'm still struggling with lag. Is there a way to get the cards (and subsequently images) to load once they're pulled into focus, or is there a better way of loading images, rather than using my drawables?

Here's how the XML looks:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/WaveTheme"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/wave_drawer_background"
    android:textColor="@color/wave_drawer_primary_text"
    android:titleTextColor="@color/wave_drawer_primary_text"
    android:subtitleTextColor="@color/wave_drawer_primary_text"
    android:elevation="4dp" />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="275dp"
            android:background="#EEE"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#EEE"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#EEE"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        >

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/dashDate"
                            android:text="@string/currentDate"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:paddingTop="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            fontPath="fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.otf"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
                            android:layout_height="15dp" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:text="FOR YOU"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:textSize="30dp"
                            android:includeFontPadding="false"
                            fontPath="fonts/Montserrat-Bold.otf"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:layout_height="40dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:background="#EEE"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        >

                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/temp_profile"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="none">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="330dp"
                            android:layout_height="180dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg">

                            <GridLayout
                                android:layout_width="310dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:columnCount="3"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                >
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="5dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/topcharts"
                                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:layout_width="125dp"/>

                                <GridLayout
                                    android:orientation="vertical">
                                    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                        app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                        android:src="@drawable/zedd"
                                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                        android:padding="1dp"
                                        android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                        app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                        android:src="@drawable/symphony"
                                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                        android:padding="1dp"
                                        android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                </GridLayout>

                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="5dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/calvinharris"
                                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="125dp"/>
                            </GridLayout>

                            <GridLayout
                                android:layout_width="310dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:columnCount="5"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                >
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/imtheone"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/littlemix2"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/kygo2"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/gallawaygirl"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/runup"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                            </GridLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="330dp"
                            android:layout_height="180dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg">

                            <GridLayout
                                android:layout_width="310dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:columnCount="3"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                >
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="5dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/oldbutgoldnew"
                                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:layout_width="145dp"/>

                                <GridLayout
                                    android:orientation="vertical">
                                    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                        app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                        android:src="@drawable/derulo"
                                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                        android:padding="1dp"
                                        android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                        app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                        android:src="@drawable/jordan"
                                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                        android:padding="1dp"
                                        android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                </GridLayout>

                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="5dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/beyonce"
                                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="105dp"/>
                            </GridLayout>

                            <GridLayout
                                android:layout_width="310dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:columnCount="5"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                >
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/mama"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ruby"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/slim"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/spice"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/viva"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                            </GridLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="330dp"
                            android:layout_height="180dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg">

                            <GridLayout
                                android:layout_width="310dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:columnCount="3"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                >
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="5dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/bedtime"
                                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:layout_width="125dp"/>

                                <GridLayout
                                    android:orientation="vertical">
                                    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                        app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                        android:src="@drawable/zedd"
                                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                        android:padding="1dp"
                                        android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                        app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                        android:src="@drawable/symphony"
                                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                        android:padding="1dp"
                                        android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                </GridLayout>

                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="5dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/calvinharris"
                                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="125dp"/>
                            </GridLayout>

                            <GridLayout
                                android:layout_width="310dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:columnCount="5"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                >
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/imtheone"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/littlemix2"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/kygo2"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/gallawaygirl"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                                    app:riv_corner_radius="3dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/runup"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:layout_width="62.5dp"/>
                            </GridLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </HorizontalScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

The XML goes on from there, but the above is what's causing the issue.

PS, please word the answers relatively simple, as I'm learning all of this on the fly and have only been coding Java properly for about 2 weeks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your question is too broad to get an actual answer but here's a few considerations:

1) reduce the depth of your layout hierarchy, the more views you nest into each other the (exponentially) slower your ui will get. why? [read here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies.html)

2) use a library to load your images, for example [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

3) instantiating all those views is probably inefficient because at any given time only a small amount of them will be visible, try to use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways to load images smoothly. Can be used to load jpg format as well.
It can also be used to reduce high resolution images to be showed efficiently.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html